# Sending email with optional attachment in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working on a form to send email where have optional attachment.

When I try to send the email without attach a file.
I got this error

**Key 'file' not found in MultiValueDict: {}**

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I would like to send it directly to the email address without upload the file to our server

forms.py

```
class jopcion(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    thecontent = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    file = forms.FileField(widget= forms.FileInput (attrs={'name': 'file'}),required=False)
```

views.py

```
def novo(request, template_name='mailme.html'):
    if request.method == "POST":
            formulario = jopcion(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            if formulario.is_valid():
                        subject = request.POST['subject']
                        message = request.POST['thecontent']
                        attach = request.FILES['file']

                        destination = 'testing@gmail.com'
                        html_content = (subject,message,attach)
                        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Customer email address', html_content, 'from@server.com', [destination])
                        msg.attach(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
                        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')#definimos el contenido como html
                        msg.send() #enviar en correo
                        return render_to_response('done.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
                    formulario = jopcion()

        ctx = {'form': formulario, 'text_dc': file}
        return render_to_response(template_name, ctx , context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Your code is not checking whether `FILES['file']` exists before trying to fetch it and attach it to the email. If it is optional then you need to first check if it exists before trying to attach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't send a file, request.FILE will be a blank dictionary-like object. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES)

Based on this, you need to check if key is present at this dict. examples:

```
 if 'file' in request.FILES:
     attach = request.FILES['file']

 #or
 attach = request.FILES.get('file')
```